# Automatic Hyperlink in my website

Tags: url, text, hyperlink

I want the URLs in my website automatically hyperlink.
I can only use Javascript, HTML, and jQuery in my website.

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to replace plain URLs with links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links)

Answer (score 1):

The search term you want is "linkify".  There are a number of solutions out there, personally I've only used this:

http://benalman.com/code/test/js-linkify/

Examples are in the source code.